# How do I find related articles with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, content-management-system, business-catalyst

I am writing some javascript functions to generate related articles. I used 'levenshtein' from Mootools to check two article titles, but the result was not too outstanding. For example, it thinks "I like pumpkin soup very much" and "pumpkin soup" are not related, because the length of the 2 strings is quite different. So I would love to try a different way to do that. Hopefully, a javascript function. The CMS I use does not allow me to change the query to database.

Comment: which CMS are you using?

Comment: A short principle is if they tagged in the same tag and category they are related

Comment: Categories/tags, and author, at a minimum. Beyond that, there are many more complex algorithms. In either case, this is something you want to do at the database and web server level, not with client-side JavaScript.

Comment: Hi, I use Business Catalyst.

Comment: You might want to consider the approach documented here: http://hovinne.com/articles/jquery-wordstats-plugin